# Google Interview Question

Tags: java, c++, hashtable

This was one of Google Interview questions.

> What is the possible problem if Hash Table grows more than 30 gb
>   (ignore problems like bad hash function )

I didn't know it. What could be satisfactory answer ?

Thanks

Comment: That depends. Do you have 30GB of RAM? That would have been the first question I asked *them*

Comment: Voting to reopen: while the question title is non-specific, the discussion of how a hashtable scales and suitable alternative are very relevant to programming. Perhaps poster could restate the question to focus on what happens to massive hashtables?

Comment: For the record, I voted to move this to programmers.stackexchange.com, but I didn't want it to be closed. Voted to reopen.

Comment: Did you ask why 30? If I understood it correctly, it would not work on 32bit systems, since you need at least 2^36 for hashmap header :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some problems :

1. [Hash Collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_%28computer_science%29) might be one of the major problem possible.
2. It will be also inefficient to make frequent disk reads when data store in disk as hash table.

Comment: why does hash collision necessarily cause extra memory?

Comment: And I don't get the second one either. How could that cost extra memory?

Comment: Why would hash collision be a problem? Usually, frequent hash collision is the result of a poor hash function, which the problem explicitly says to ignore. Imagine that the hash function for this particular set of objects in the 30 GiB hash table were each hashed to a different value. 30 GiB is addressable by 35-bit integers, so the imposed requirement is only that 5 bytes of each object be unique. That seems reasonable.

Comment: I think #1 is not the answer, #2 is more likely to answer the quesiton because: unless you actually have 30Gb of RAM, the data is stored on the disk(HDD), which has high throughput, but high latency for random access (which is kind of what a hash table is all about).
IDK if SSD could improve this though.

Answer (score 22):

The answer partly depends on whether they are talking about a classic hashtable implementation (like HashTable / HashMap in Java) or something more sophisticated. In the end, 30 GB of memory is still quite big for a single machine/VM by today's standards.

So think about what's going on underneath:

1. It has to read write at an arbitrary position in some massive array.
2. It has to grow if it fills up beyond some measure; see 'load factor' in Java implementation.
3. In a garbage collected language/implementation, all the objects stored in the hash table need to be inspected by the garbage collector

Which leads to the following problems:

1. It is unclear that even today's operating systems deal well with allocating chunks of memory in the tens of GBs
2. For simplicity, say that half of the table was actually used by the table itself (not the key and value objects). So there is a 15 gb array inside. So every time the table grows, you need to allocate at least *another* 15 gb
3. Even if a tens of GB array was allocated, the OS would page some of this memory. Since we are assuming a good hash function, we will break page caching if we use most of the data in the array. There will be a lot of page faults.
4. Let's say we *don't* use all the data. Some keys are used frequently, and others are not. To illustrate, say that each key-value is tiny -- 128 bytes. And for simplicity, say that we store everything in the hash table as values. So 30G/128 = ~ 250M entries. But say 25k commonly used keys. (25k / 250M = 0.01%). But with good a hash function, these would be evenly scattered across the massive array. Even with small page sizes -- say 4kb, the 25K (entries) * 128 bytes (entry size) = ~3.5Mb worth of commonly used data costs us 25K (entries) * 4K (page size) = ~ 100Mb of memory that needs to be kept paged in... at a whopping 3.5% efficiency!
5. In the Java world, practitioners don't recommend heap sizes larger that 4 - 8Gb. Sure there's stuff like [Azul](http://www.azulsystems.com/), but that simply proves the point -- a typical garbage collector don't scale to these sizes very well.

I agree with other posters that Google is looking for distributed as a solution. But I think at the heart, a simple hashtable stops scaling beyond a point. In the above,

1. You would have to distribute if all the entries are accessed relatively evenly
2. If some are accessed a majority of the time, using two maps (one for most frequently used) can buy you a lot.
3. In the Java world, using specialized maps that store data off the heap can buy you performance too; see [Peter Lawrey's work](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011/08/added-memory-mapped-support-to.html) for example.
4. Even simply striping the underlying array in a hashtable (like Java's ConcurrentHashMap does) can buy you major improvements when you have to grow the hashtable.

Answer (score 7):

I think the interviewer was expecting something on the lines of [Distributed Hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_hash_table), since a 30GB hash table cannot be stored on a single machine (at least in the current 64-bit world); From my personal experience, quite a few of the google Qs revolve around distributed computing, map-reduce etc.,

Comment: 30 GiB is definitely addressable on a 64-bit machine. In theory, it's even addressable on a 32-bit machine if the operating system supports something like Windows' [Address Windowing Extensions API](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Address_Windowing_Extensions).

Comment: These days, high end machines can easily accommodate > 1TiB of RAM ... if you have the money; e.g. https://www.crn.com.au/news/aws-launches-2tb-ram-super-machine-410273